# Get value from parent template

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery Tmpl and Knockout. I have templates:

**Template 1**:

```
{{each (index, model) Models}}
<div data-bind="template: 'template2', foreach: model.SubModels"></div>
{{/each}}
```

**Template 2**:

```
<div>${FieldFromSubModel} {__Here i need index from template 1__}</div>
```

How can I pass index variable to the second tempalate?

*Please note, my templates are far more complex, so the structure should stay as it is.*

Comment: Did you try `$parentContext.$index`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, only $parent call. Let me try, but a little bit later. I reorganized all my templates, so it would be hard to return to previous state. Thanks for the comment and +1 for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be using jquery templates, you can use the parameter `templateOptions` to pass extra options:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'template2', data: model.SubModels, templateOptions: {yourIndex: $index}}"></div>
```

Now you can use `$item.yourIndex` in **Template 2**.

Otherwise `$parentContext.$index` maybe also do the trick.